# Some questions on the feasibility of GPU as the primary processor for a system

Tags: gpu, hardware-rec, mini-itx, gpgpu

1) Are there any manufactures that offer boards that have GPGPU's as their primary processors out on the market at all? Ones that would fit into a mini-ITX form factor would be of interest but the more GPU's the better would be desirable.

2) If so what OS's would be available?

Thanks for any recommendations. If this is the incorrect spot, my apologies.

EDIT: Probably should clarify that the reason for my inquiry is a project that I'm putting together would be performing a lot of number crunching/repetitive tasks, which from research has led me to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a GPU if it dosen't do graphics ;) it would be a GPGPU then. You'd want to go for a design that's massively multithreaded and with very good floating point performance.

Cell processors are [really very specialised power architecture based systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Architecture), so that's one option

alternately, load up a system with GPGPUs such as the [tesla](http://www.nvidia.com/object/personal-supercomputing.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any real GPU-only devices, I think the closest you can probably get is the playstation 3 with its cell processor. To my understanding, GPUs are very poorly optimized for memory management (no free lunch!) so they're not really suitable for doing anything other than repetitive simple mathematics.

Comment: Thankfully it's the kind of tasks that I'm looking to use these systems for.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there are none. The reason being that GPUs are really only efficient for certain math related operations. They also lack the instructions necessary to do the things required by an Operating System.

Consequently there are no operating systems. However there are frameworks for having code run on the GPU. These are called "GPGPU" Microsoft has DirectX Compute, CUDA, OpenCL etc.

Naturally you are still limited by the limitations of the GPU and the instruction set that it supports and is optimized. So unless you are doing heavy number crunching/analysis you may have difficulty efficiently harnessing the power.